# How can a ring oscillator work without burning?

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator

I built this ring oscillator and it works fine. After a while I wondered how can it work without breaking.

I am powering it with 5 volts so at start let's say capacitor is charged with 0 volts and a **blue** node is at 0V. So capacitor starts to charge via R1. When it reaches Vih min (~3.2 V) for IC2A the voltage level is flipped (so voltage at **blue** node will become high) and now is a **red** node at Voh + Vih (5 + 3.2 = 8.2 V) which is much higher than allowed from datasheet. This voltage is connected via R2 to input pin.

I've used this oscillator for maybe a year now and it's working fine. The IC is an SN74HC00N.

What I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you actually measured the node to see if the voltage is 8.2V? Considering CMOS devices will usually have clamp diodes on the inputs, this suggests the the errant voltage is clamped. And since the relative energy is low, the clamp diodes don't melt down.

Comment: You could put a 5V Zener diode from the junction of C1, R1, and R2 to ground.  That would clamp and negative voltage as well as anything > 5V.

Comment: Clamping diodes might be a case, I am going to measure it.

Comment: Protection diodes. And the value of R2 which will limit the current into them.

Comment: Thank you guys, you were right. It is protected by a diodes. Would you mind post an answer so I can close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *red node at Voh + Vih (5 + 3.2 = 8.2 V) which is much
> higher than allowed from datasheet.*

Resistors R1 and R2 restrict the current that can flow into the TTL output and input nodes. It won't burn. Input current is limited to much lower than the 1 mA limit specified in the data sheet. It can't happen. I mean, why else would R2 be present. The internal protection diodes are perfectly adequate with such a small current injection.

Answer (score 3):

> When it's reach a Vih min (~3.2 V) for IC2A the voltage level is
> flipped

It is never "flipped" abruptly; rather, before the "flipping" moment and some time after the IC2B gate behaves as an inverting amplifier. Not very good amplifier, in a sense it is not quite linear and its gain is not great, but still more than unity. So the other gates in your circuit, they act as an inverting and partially clamping amplifiers, and this chain of inverting amplifiers is the thing you call a "ring oscillator". Certainly, there is a power consumption in this circuit, but not as great as to be able to "burn" the components. Try and simulate it in the simulator and you'll see.

PS; NB The ring oscillator can be (and often is) implemented without external resistors and capacitors, only an odd number (5, 7, ...) of chained CMOS inverters in a ring.

Comment: And, for the record, SN74HC00N is a **CMOS** device, featuring clamping diodes: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc00.pdf , page 9, **8.3 Balanced CMOS Push-Pull Outputs**, **8.4 Standard CMOS Inputs**, **8.5 Clamp Diode Structure**.